# UTF-16 to UTF8 with WideCharToMultiByte problems

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

```
int main(){
//"Chào" in Vietnamese
wchar_t utf16[] =L"\x00ff\x00fe\x0043\x0000\x0068\x0000\x00EO\x0000\x006F";
//Dump utf16: FF FE 43 0 68 0 E 4F 0 6F (right)
int size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8,0,utf16,-1,NULL,0,NULL,NULL);
char *utf8 = new char[size];
int k = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8,0,utf16,-1,utf8 ,size,NULL,NULL);
//Dump utf8: ffffffc3 fffffbf ffffc3 ffffbe 43 0
}
```

Here is my code, when i convert it string into UTF-8, it show a wrong result, so what is wrong with my code?

Comment: For starters, you probably want to convert your whole array, even though it is not a wide character string: It has embedded zeroes.

Comment: Also, unicode is not a synonym of utf-16.

Comment: @Deduplicator unfortunately Microsoft thinks otherwise.

Comment: So can you suggest a solution for this ?, how to make a properly utf-16 string in C++

Comment: @MarkRansom: No reason to add to the confusion. Also, the OP will surely stumble across UTF-32 soon, as he already did for UTF-8.

Comment: why somebody remove the answer, it really help for me. There are nothing wrong about the answer. BTW, thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wchar_t utf16[] = L"\uFEFFChào";
int size = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    std::printf("%X ", utf16[i]);
}
```

This program prints out: `FEFF 43 68 E0 6F`

If printing out each `wchar_t` you've read from a file prints out `FF FE 43 0 68 0 E 4F 0 6F` then the UTF-16 data is not being read from the file correctly.. Those values represent the UTF-16 string: `L"ÿþC\0h\0à\0o".

You don't show your code for reading from the file, but here's one way to do it correctly:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10504278/365496

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the file incorrectly. Your dump of the input is showing single bytes in wide characters. Your dump of the output is the byte sequence that results from encoding `L"\xff\xfe\x43"` to UTF-8. The string is being truncated at the first `\x0000` in the input.